# Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter - using the values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins so this is probably an easy one.  I have the Extended Choice Parameter plugin installed.  I'm using the Multi Select parameter type to pick from a list of servers (SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3)  I've set Source for Value, Default Value, and Value Description.

I save it, and it looks great.  I can pick any or all servers for the build.  Now for the big question.. how do I use these values in the build?  Basically I have a step in the build that can take in a comma separated list that is called by a shell command:

```
d:\python\deploy.py?serverlist=$blah
```

What do I put in for $blah to use that list of servers?

Just to be clear, if I'm on command line I would do the following:

```
d:\python\deploy.py?serverlist=SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I just cannot find it in the docs or an example.

Comment: Can you get the environment variables from this ```https://localhost:8080/job/TEST/10/injectedEnvVars/```?

Comment: Yes, I can see go there and see the parameters like this:  SERVERLIST SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3

Comment: is it really this simple?  d:\python\deploy.py?serverlist=$SERVERLIST

Comment: AH ha!  Looks like depending on how I use it I do $SERVERLIST or %SERVERLIST%  thanks for showing me the way to find the parameters, that did the trick!

Comment: If you'd like to write up a little answer (get params here, use them like this) I'll be happy to accept it, or I can do so.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or should I just delete this question?

Comment: I added my answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get the servers list like this

```
d:\python\deploy.py?serverlist=$SERVERLIST
```

or this on Windows

```
d:\python\deploy.py?serverlist=%SERVERLIST%
```

To see the list of environment variables which we could you, try this URL (change `localhost` by your Jenkins URL, `TEST` by the job name, `10` by the build number)

https://localhost:8080/job/TEST/10/injectedEnvVars/

**UPDATE** to @sniperd's edition:

This URL will shows us the parameters list in the Job:

http://localhost:8080/job/TEST/59/parameters/