# How to include git branch name as variable for ant build.xml

Tags: git, jenkins, ant, sonarqube

I'm trying to use the git branch name as a variable so that I can include it in the SonarQube project key.
Does anyone know of how I can do this? I'm on Windows if that helps.
I've tried doing things like this:

```
property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${GIT_BRANCH}"
```

or setting environment variables in Jenkins and calling those but I can't seem to get it.

Thanks in advance :)

Additional info:

I'm building the project from Jenkins and the part where it fails is when I call `ant sonar`.
Using `${GIT_BRANCH}` results in this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PR Projects\jobs\PR_JmxMonitor_RPM\workspace\projects\JmxMonitor\build.xml:132: Validation of project reactor failed: o "${GIT_BRANCH}" is not a valid project or module key. Allowed characters are alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with at least one non-digit."
```

Comment: Could you clearly specify what you want to do? Should it be done with Jenkins? And what has ant to do with it?

Comment: You could review my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963102/691530

Comment: You could see the list of environment variables which you could use at https://localhost:8080/job/TEST/10/injectedEnvVars/

Comment: Are you sure "${GIT_BRANCH}" is populated?

Answer (score 2):

When I went to `localhost:8080/job/TEST/10/injectedEnvVars` (for example) I couldn't see `GIT_BRANCH` as an environment variable. I realized I hadn't selected '`inject environment variables to the build process`' in the build environment.

Then in `build.xml`, I made `value="$(branch)"` and added `-Dbranch=%GIT_BRANCH%` to my command line.

Thanks all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,
But you have use Job --> Source Code Management -> Git , then GIT_BRANCH will work.

```
property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
```